# Create auto-generate a slug from Doctrine prefixed by year

Tags: doctrine-orm, slug, symfony-2.4, doctrine-extensions

I would like to auto-generate a slug from Doctrine in my Symfony 2.4 application, where the slug is unique based upon the year that the record was created. I am using DoctrineExtensions.

For my blog records i want the route to be `/blog/{year}/{slug}`

So lets say i have these two records

`id: 1
title: My Blog Title
createdAt: 2013-08-14 18:48:21`

`id: 2
title: My Blog Title
createdAt: 2014-02-01 17:12:10`

I want both slugs to be `my-blog-title`, as they are unique records based upon createdAt

So my two routes would then be

`/blog/2013/my-blog-title
/blog/2014/my-blog-title`

However, i don't seem to be able to get this to work:

Here is the relevent part of my orm.yml

`fields:
        title:
            type: text
        slug:
            type: text
            gedmo:
                slug:
                    unique_base: createdAt
                    fields:
                        - title
        createdAt:
            type: datetime
            gedmo:
                timestampable:
                    on: create`

This works, because createdAt is unique for ALL records as it is almost imossible for any two of my records to have the same created date down to the exact same second.

So if i add a third record:

`id: 3
title: My Blog Title
createdAt: 2014-03-02 17:12:10`

It lets me use the same slug - `my-blog-title`

In my orm.yml file i want to be able to do something like

`unique_base: createdAt("Y")`

So that only the year of my created date is used as the base, so i can have the same slug if the records are in different years, but not the same slugs if the records are in the same year.

I know i can pull the date into the slug itself

`2014-my-blog-title` but it needs to look like `2014/my-blog-title`

Could someone please help with this?

Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out a workaround, or maybe it's the right way to do it!?

Since i need unique_base to refer to the year i created a record, and not the full timestamp, i made a new field called slugBase.

slugBase is not unique and is slugabble from the createdAt field with the format "Y". So if a record is created on 2014-03-02 slugBase will automatically set to "2014"

So now, when the title changes, slug will only create a slug by the title, using slugBase as the unique_base

Here is my orm.yml

```
fields:
    title:
        type: text
    slugBase:
        type: text
        gedmo:
            slug:
                unique: false
                dateFormat: "Y"
                fields:
                    - createdAt
    slug:
        type: text
        gedmo:
            slug:
                unique_base: slugBase
                fields:
                    - title
    createdAt:
        type: datetime
        gedmo:
            timestampable:
                on: create
```

This works nicely as i don't have to do anything manually each time a record is created/updated.

But obviously, when looking up a record i will have to search by slugBase and slug. So my new route will be `/blog/{slugBase}/{slug}`